# Два пользователя онлайн

Tags: ajax

Нужно заставить взаимодействовать двух пользователей он-лайн через браузер.
Вопрос в том на какой технологии это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос поставлен неконкретно. Если задача сводится к тому, чтобы, например, устроить чат двух пользователей на веб-странице, то есть **много** подходов для его реализации.

[Например](http://html5demos.com/web-socket):

- клиентский код на HTML5 + JavaScript с общением через вебсокеты,
- серверный код на Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS + Redis
Я бы Вам посоветовал.